# TFS Absolute beginner: TF249051: No URL can be found that corresponds to the following server

Tags: tfs

This is an absolute beginner question in TFS SDK:

I am trying to connect to TFS server using the code

```
TeamFoundationServer teamFoundationServer =
               TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer(X);
```

X is server name

I am getting an error like

```
TF249051: No URL can be found that corresponds to the following server name: X
Verify that the server name is correct.
```

However I am able to connect to the TFS server from VS2010 using Team->Connect to TFserver menu option

Comment: Figured out the issue
it was to add a subfolder name after the server name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TeamFoundation Server Factory is deprecated.  You should use TeamFoundationProjectCollection.

And, yes, under TFS 2010, you'll need the folder.

Comment: the same problem repeats :(
I have given the folder name in the server as well and am able to browse TFS using VS2010
the VSTS deployment is moved to NLB now
Is this a cause for the recurrence?

Comment: I get the same error using my Addin VS, VS 2012, TFS 2008, Windows 8. But the same my Addin VS is OK using VS 2012, TFS 2008 and Windows 7.